# Is there a bean event for cancel button in PrimeFaces upload component?

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces, listener

We are using the primefaces for file upload handling in our web application. The upload component becomes visible, upon some event on the page (button pressed). We would like to be able to catch the event when CANCEL button is pressed, in order to use it to hide the upload component back. Any advise? Javascript or CSS would not do the work, as we also need to do some server logic for this.

Code:

```
                <h:form id="uploadFileForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" rendered="#{filesMenu.enableFileUpload}">
                    <p:fileUpload style="font-size:12px;"
                        fileUploadListener="#{filesMenu.handleFileUpload}"
                        mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="false"
                        update="msgUpload , :formFilesListId , :formFilesListId:dataTableSimpleFilesId, :createNewFileFromSelectionForm"
                        sizeLimit="100000" fileLimit="1" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(cfg)$/" />
                    <p:growl id="msgUpload" showDetail="true" />
                </h:form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Catch the cancel-button click with Javascript/JQuery. On the one hand you can invoke an hidden button on your jsf page which triggers the server logic. On the other hand you can trigger the following component from Javascript :

```
<p:remoteCommand name="functionName" action="#{yourBean.yourMethod}">
```

Catch the cancel button :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".ui-fileUpload").on("click",".cancel",function() {

      //Approach remoteCommand 
      functionName();

      //Approach hidden button
      $(".jQueryTohiddenButtonClass").click();
}
```

Probably you have to customize the jQuery path, so they fit to your demands.

Comment: Catch the cancel-button click with Javascript. How? :) thanks

Comment: Thanks for the update, with some modifications - it worked great :)

Comment: I am glad that I could help. Unfortunately I had no time for a more detailed solution.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to hide the cancel-button completely with

```
.ui-fileupload-cancel {
     display: none;
}
```

and create your own button instead which calls an `action/actionListener` and hides the dialog.

I went even further and hid all 3 buttons and created my own save button too, which called `PF('fileupload_widgetvar').upload();` in oncomplete. Then you'd need to have some javascript to make the page wait until the upload is finished, as the ajax is asynchonous so you can't redirect/hide the dialog right away. Let me know if you want that code.